# Mongo Db: Deleting a record from collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am working on a project using meteor and new to mongo db. I have a collection named "addressDB" and a table in html displays all the records of addressDB collection, as followed:
[image]

When i click on "-" button the record should be removed from table. I search lot of places but no success till now. Help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could this as the event handler for the button

```
MyCollection.remove({ this._id });
```

Where MyCollection is the name of the collection of the data.

This works if you've used `{{#each }}` to loop each of the items in the list. So it provides the context to `this` in your button's handler.

e.g

```
Template.MyTemplate.events({
    'click .buttonClass': function() { addressDB.remove({ this._id }); }
});
```

and your button:

```
<button class="buttonClass">-</button>
```

Comment: thanks it worked! But there was a slight change in syntax. It was MyCollection.remove(this_id);